# How to choose an option in mat select using ANY google chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, angular-material

I have a problem with selecting an option in mat-select with the use of google chrome extensions. Extensions can fulfill inputs but mat-selects remains untouched.

I've tried to use extensions like: Autofill, Form-O-Filler. By default extensions can't reach mat-selects. To obtain my goal I used javascript code to select option/value but it didnt work.

My summarized mat-select looks like this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="name">
    <mat-select formControlName="name"
                [mctPristine]="group?.name"
                name="name"
                id="name">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name">
        name 
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I have used code below to choose value:

```
document.getElementById('name').value='Patryk';
```

and this:

```
document.getElementById('name').selectedIndex='0';
```

Unfortunately this does not work at all. Should i change my javascript code? Or chrome extension?

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7246. Looks like it's not implemented.